# Using streamreader (how do I skip a line if a special character is found)?

Tags: c#, file, filter, contains, streamreader

I'm currently using streamreader and filestream to read a txt file and dump it into a listbox.  Every other line in this text file contains a special character, which is the curly brace. e.g. { or }

I like to figure out how do I skip reading all the lines that contain "{}" into my listbox. But I still like to stream the rest of the text file.

Currently, this is what I'm using in my code. But obviously it's still writing the lines with curly braces in them.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void ReadUsingStreamReader()
    {
        char[] chars = { '{', '}' }; 
        string characters = new string(chars);
        string FileName = "Path To File"; 
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {           
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
             {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {                    
                    string  line =sr.ReadToEnd();                     
                    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
                        foreach(string FileText in readText)
                        {
                            if (FileText.Contains(characters))
                            {
                                //Do nothing
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              listBox1.Items.Add(FileText);
                            }

                        }                         
                }                            
             }
        }
```

Okay, I changed the code and this here seems to work fine.

```
private void ReadUsingStreamReader()
    {
        string FileName = "Path To File";
        char[] chars = { '{', '}' }; 
        string characters = new string(chars);           

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
                    foreach (string FileText in readText)
                    {
                        foreach (char c in characters)
                        {

                            if (FileText.Contains(c)) continue;
                            listBox1.Sorted = true;
                            listBox1.Items.Add(FileText);
                            break;                                       

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

      }
```

Comment: Please clarify. you cann't skip reading but you can skip adding to listbox as you currently do..What is your goal?

Comment: Hard to guess what this code is trying to do.  Looks like you googled two pieces of code and tried to glue them together without understanding what they do.  Get rid of File.ReadAllLines() to start solving your problem, pay attention to the *line* variable instead.

Comment: @ apomene: There is a file being created, then I'm trying to read it when it's done being written to. Every other line has the curly braces in them.  I just want to filter that line out completely that has curely braces in them from being added into my listbox. But add the rest of the text file into my listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for each character separately:

```
foreach(string FileText in readText)
{
    foreach(char c in chars) 
        if (FileText.Contains(c)) continue;
    ....
}
```

Also, I'd read from the stream line by line...

```
string  line = sr.ReadLine();
```